# Log events from another assembly in a seperate log4net log

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I have the following log4net configuration

```xml
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs\\CurrentLog.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <priority value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Is it possible to log the events from a different assembly in a different file? For example, messages from

> Castle.Facilities.NhibernateIntegration

If not that, is there a better way of filtering the events?
I do not want to limit the stream to only errors.

Comment: Did you mean to show a rolling file appender or an event log appender? You had mixed configuration from both. I removed the event log stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loggers can be configured by their names. If you're following [idiomatic](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html#logger%20hierarchy) log4net practices, your loggers are named by their full `Namespace.TypeName`. You can assign appenders to loggers in two ways.

The first is to embed the special appender directly

```xml
<logger name="Castle.Facilities.NhibernateIntegration">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender name="CastleNhIntegrationAppender" type="...">
        <!-- put the full appender configuration here -->
    </appender>
</logger>
```

Or to define the appender and reference it in the logger

```xml
<appender name="CastleNhIntegrationAppender" type="...">
    <!-- put the full appender configuration here -->
</appender>

<logger name="Castle.Facilities.NhibernateIntegration">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="CastleNhIntegrationAppender" />
</logger>
```